# Include kernel headers correctly

Tags: header, include, kernel

I want to do some kernel programming and I am running Ubuntu 16.04, but there occur problems caused by including.
Example: I wanted to include "sys/types.h".
Then there was a fatal error that there does not exist a file or directory with that name. Then I installed some packages and it still was not found. After I searched types.h myself I found it in /usr/include/sys/types.h.
So I included

```
#include </usr/include/sys/types.h>.
```

But now there is the following error:
"/usr/include/sys/types.h:25:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory"
I have a feeling that I am missing something but I don't know what.
I tried the following stuff:
-sudo apt-get update
-sudo apt-get install linux-source
-sudo apt-get install build-essential
-sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
-sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
-sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
I am really thankful if someone has a working advice!

Comment: In short: User space headers shouldn't be used when develop kernel code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.